# Record Exception w/ AWS X-Ray .NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-xray

I am having an issue with recording an exception to AWS X-Ray.

Here is what is in Application_Error:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();

        if (exception != null)
        {
            var InnerException = exception.InnerException;

            Session["error"] = String.Format("{0} ::: {1}", exception.Message, exception.StackTrace);
            try
            {
                AWSXRayRecorder.Instance.AddException(exception);
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                // ignore errors for XRay
            }
        }
        Server.ClearError();

    }
```

However, an error is thrown on the AddException line stating "Segment doesn't exist in CallContext"

First time trying to get X-Ray going. Any advice? Are there any tutorials that anybody has run into that may help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior of XRay is to throw an exception if you are attempting to access a `Segment`, and none is currently setup in the current context.  You can see the [default behavior mentioned in the environment variables documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-dotnet-configuration.html#xray-sdk-dotnet-configuration-envvars).

As that documentation points out, you can set the `AWS_XRAY_CONTEXT_MISSING` environment variable on your EC2 instance to `LOG_ERROR` to adjust this behavior.

Alternatively, you can use the `ContextMissingStrategy` property to change this behavior within the code.  [Documentation link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray-sdk-for-dotnet/latest/reference/html/P_Amazon_XRay_Recorder_Core_AWSXRayRecorder_ContextMissingStrategy.htm).

Comment: Ah, ok... I was beginning the segment in Application_BeginRequest() and ending it in Application_EndRequest(). That was not working. I have now wrapped this begin and end around the the AddException() which is now working.

Comment: I don't know enough about .NET web architecture to provide much further help, but I imagine you want to create the segment in some pre-filter (proxy) to your web server code, and then close the segment in some post-filter (proxy) to the same web server code.

Answer (score 2):

Set `AWS_XRAY_CONTEXT_MISSING` to `LOG_ERROR` can stop AddException to throw the "Segment doesn't exist" exception, but this also means nothing gets recorded to XRay service.

To really solve the problem, you should create a Segment at the beginning of your logic. When you are writing an ASP.NET Web API application, you can add an interceptor to automatically create a segment for each incoming request. There is a sample application you can try.

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-xray-dotnet-webapp